# RestSharp post request gets different status when called as sync and async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await, restsharp

I'm writting a proxy where I can send post request in asynchronous way.
The method always get "Not Found" response when executed as async and OK when sync.

Sync method (OK Status)
[image]

Async method (Not Found status)
[image]

What could I be doing wrong since the request is the very same for both?

Comment: What happens if you swap the calls?

Comment: Have you tried to use something like Fiddler to find out what's going on the wire? Or enable System.Net tracing?

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. The problem was so naive. I was calling ExecuteGet instead of Execute for a post method.

Comment: Should I delete this question? It doesn't contribute in any way :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you replace the second call with the restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync?

Comment: Omg, that was the problem. I did'nt notice that "get" part in the method firm.
Thanks for noticing it.